# Re-opening a question

Tags: discussion

I edited this question: [Why do fingers swell during cold winters?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31776/why-do-fingers-swell-during-cold-winters) during the close-vote process.

I think the question is valid as both heat and cold appear to cause swelling, which is counter-intuitive and an interesting phenomenon. I think it has the right to survive as it now contains appropriate background information. I voted for re-opening.

The duplicate question of this is put on hold and I was hoping to delete this first duplicate question https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/why-do-fingers-swell-during-winters.